# Pointer to array in array

Tags: arrays, pointers

I'm programming C and trying to point to an array in an array. Let's assume there is an array

array1[10][8]

I'm collecting now data in another function with a second array. Let's assume

array2[8]

What's the easiest way to get the data of array2 in array1[0] and the next time in array1[1]...

Comment: This is quite broad. What sort of data do the arrays store?

Comment: All data are the same, uint8_t.

Comment: @Mr.Knackwurst as far as I understand, you wish to create some kind of enumerator functionality, right? If you confirm it, I'll share my idea in an answer

Comment: @Géza: I'm not sure, maybe. I have a function generating a struct that contains 8 Bytes (array2). I'm collecting this 8 Bytes in another function within an second 2D-array (array1). The 2D-array is updated in different timeslots and stores new but also old results of array2. The function working with the 2D-array sends a pointer to the 1D-function pointing on the address where the function with array two have to place the 8 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Knackwurst I think I just got what you want! The "2D array" is a ring buffer that you are filling with your "1D function", from the occassionally arriving 8 long vector. Read this: https://www.google.hu/amp/s/embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/4/6/circular-buffers-in-cc%3Fformat%3Damp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array is uint8_t. You can use first method for initialization or when you wish to copy data repeatedly. Second method can be used for random writes.

```
#include <cstdlib>

uint8_t array1[10][8], array2[8];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        memcpy(array1[i], array2, 8 * sizeof(array2[0]));
}
```

or

```
#include <cstdlib>

uint8_t array1[10][8], array2[8];
int index = 0
int main()
{
    memcpy(array1[index], array2, 8 * sizeof(array2[0]));
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I'm programming in simple C, not C++ and am not sure if memspy will work there as well.

Comment: memcpy is a standard C function from library stdlib.h

Comment: Maybe it's important to let you know that it's a microcontroller application.

Comment: memcpy works in embedded C. I have used it in gcc 4.8 (Infineon XMC4500 and STM32F micro-controllers)

Comment: Perfect, I don't know memcpy and will check it.

Comment: What micro-controller and compiler are you using?

Comment: It's an STM32F3xx with MDK.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm not sure how to handle with pointers as explained above, but will give it a try.